# Unable to scrape different fields from two different depth simultaneously

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've written a script in python to scrape the `name`,`address` and `phone` of different retaurants from the landing page of a webpage and parse the `author` and `review` from each of the restaurants inner page.

> ***I would like to generate results using `yield` within `get_additional_info(link)` function but print the same within `get_links(link)` function together with other results.***

[Website address](https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=restaurant&geo_location_terms=San+Francisco%2C+CA)

I've written so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

url = "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=restaurant&geo_location_terms=San+Francisco%2C+CA"
base = "https://www.yellowpages.com"

def get_links(link):
    res = requests.get(link,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".v-card"):

        inner_link = item.select_one("a.business-name")
        author,review = get_additional_info(urljoin(base,inner_link.get('href')))

        title = inner_link.text
        address = item.select_one("p.adr").get_text(strip=True)
        phone = item.select_one(".phone").text
        yield title,address,phone,author,review


def get_additional_info(link):
    res = requests.get(link,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for elem in soup.select("article[class='clearfix']"):
        try:
            author = elem.select_one(".review-info a.author").text
        except AttributeError: author = ""
        try:
            review = elem.select_one(".review-response > p").text
        except AttributeError: review = ""

        yield author, review

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for item in get_links(url):
        print(item)
```

If I run the above script, it throws the following error pointing at the line `author,review = get_additional_info(urljoin(base,inner_link.get('href')))`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\demo.py", line 36, in <module>
    for item in get_links(url):
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\demo.py", line 14, in get_links
    author,review = get_additional_info(urljoin(base,inner_link.get('href')))
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

All the fields that I wish to grab have been defined (the selectors) properly.

This is how [the output](https://filebin.net/b1vf5ieif36gx6he) I'm after:

> PS I wish to stick to the way I've already tried, meaning I do not want to parse everything from inner pages as the data are useless to me.

Comment: The `get_additional_info()` function returns a generator; you have to consume this generator in order to get the items, or change the function to return those items if you don't need a generator.

Comment: Can I return all those items in `get_additional_info()` function and print the same in `get_links(link)`? If I return the value the way it is, the function will only remember the last iteration.

Comment: Well, you could add all items in a list, but it can be avoided. In order to unpack the generator you have to know how many items it will return, which is probably not possible in this case. What you could do instead, is iterate over the generator and unpack each item, as is done in Andrej's answer.

Comment: Thank you so much sir @t.m.adam. This is what I needed to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you right, you want to "join" links and additional info. One way to do it is this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

from textwrap import shorten

url = "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=restaurant&geo_location_terms=San+Francisco%2C+CA"
base = "https://www.yellowpages.com"

def get_links(session, link):
    res = session.get(link,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0'})

    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for item in soup.select(".v-card"):

        inner_link = item.select_one("a.business-name")

        title = inner_link.text
        address = item.select_one("p.adr").get_text(strip=True)
        phone = item.select_one(".phone").text

        for author, review in get_additional_info(session, urljoin(base,inner_link.get('href'))):
            yield title,address,phone,author,review


def get_additional_info(session, link):
    res = session.get(link,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0'})

    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    for elem in soup.select("article[class='clearfix']"):
        try:
            author = elem.select_one(".review-info a.author").text
        except AttributeError: author = ""
        try:
            review = elem.select_one(".review-response > p").text
        except AttributeError: review = ""

        yield author, review

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with requests.session() as s:
        # this sets all cookies
        res = s.get("https://www.yellowpages.com", headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0'}).text

        for title,address,phone,author,review in get_links(s, url):
            print('{: <30}{: <30}{: <20}{: <20}{}'.format(shorten(title, 30), shorten(address, 30), shorten(phone, 20), shorten(author, 20), shorten(review, 60)))
```

Prints:

```
El Toreador Restaurant        50 W Portal Ave, San [...]    (415) 347-3294      Mark I.             Their food is good but i think they need to improve on [...]
El Toreador Restaurant        50 W Portal Ave, San [...]    (415) 347-3294      Cathy L.            This place is pretty much my go to place is I want [...]
El Toreador Restaurant        50 W Portal Ave, San [...]    (415) 347-3294      Mary C.             They have so many things in here worth going in here [...]
El Toreador Restaurant        50 W Portal Ave, San [...]    (415) 347-3294      Claude R.           The appetizers in here are enough to make you ask for [...]
El Toreador Restaurant        50 W Portal Ave, San [...]    (415) 347-3294      Felicia M.          How can this be? This place looks like magic and their [...]
El Toreador Restaurant        50 W Portal Ave, San [...]    (415) 347-3294      Jose H.             I feel like I just got from Mexico, we went here last [...]
El Toreador Restaurant        50 W Portal Ave, San [...]    (415) 347-3294                          Authentic Mexican. Always busy and the house salsa is [...]
El Toreador Restaurant        50 W Portal Ave, San [...]    (415) 347-3294                          I'm disappointed. The decor is ecclectic and fun, the [...]
El Toreador Restaurant        50 W Portal Ave, San [...]    (415) 347-3294                          This used to be one of my favorite restaurants until I [...]
El Toreador Restaurant        50 W Portal Ave, San [...]    (415) 347-3294                          I came to this restarnt for a birthday of a friend of [...]
El Toreador Restaurant        50 W Portal Ave, San [...]    (415) 347-3294                          The reviews here, which I consulted before going, were [...]
El Toreador Restaurant        50 W Portal Ave, San [...]    (415) 347-3294                          I have been told to give it a try.Food is on [...]
El Toreador Restaurant        50 W Portal Ave, San [...]    (415) 347-3294                          Great food... love the empalmada... sort of like a [...]
El Toreador Restaurant        50 W Portal Ave, San [...]    (415) 347-3294                          Definitely the best Mexican restaurant in town!... [...]
El Toreador Restaurant        50 W Portal Ave, San [...]    (415) 347-3294                          This place has been consistenly good for a few years. [...]
El Toreador Restaurant        50 W Portal Ave, San [...]    (415) 347-3294                          So-so Mexican food served by a vaguely condescending, [...]
El Toreador Restaurant        50 W Portal Ave, San [...]    (415) 347-3294                          since the place is small, it gets crowded quickly and [...]
El Toreador Restaurant        50 W Portal Ave, San [...]    (415) 347-3294                          Go early if you don't want to wait. They don't take [...]
El Toreador Restaurant        50 W Portal Ave, San [...]    (415) 347-3294                          A great place where you belong like part of the [...]
House Of Prime Rib            1906 Van Ness Ave, San [...]  (415) 636-6476      Keith Y.            Loved this place. Food and service was amazing
House Of Prime Rib            1906 Van Ness Ave, San [...]  (415) 636-6476      Quintrell P.        Was really hungry and needed a place to get some [...]
House Of Prime Rib            1906 Van Ness Ave, San [...]  (415) 636-6476      Len K.              I'm not usually a fan of red meat, but I'm definitely [...]
House Of Prime Rib            1906 Van Ness Ave, San [...]  (415) 636-6476      Emm C.              I haven't been able to see San Francisco, one of my [...]
House Of Prime Rib            1906 Van Ness Ave, San [...]  (415) 636-6476      James O.            For me, it`s one of the best ribs in town, I give [...]
House Of Prime Rib            1906 Van Ness Ave, San [...]  (415) 636-6476      Jing H.             This is one of the best places if you are craving for [...]

...etc.
```

Comment: You can shorten `for title,address,phone,author,review in get_links(s, url):` to only `for title in get_links(s, url):` which will still produce the same result.